# Storing images in file system, amazon-s3 datastores

Tags: image, amazon-s3, storage, filesystems

There has been numerous discussions related to storing images (or binary data) in the database or file system (Refer: [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay))

We have decided to use the file system for storing images and relevant image specific metadata  in the database itself in the short term and migrate to an amazon s3 based data store in the future. Note: the data store will be used to store user pictures, photos from group meetings ...

Are there any off the shelf java based open source frameworks which provide an abstraction to handle storage and retrieval via http for the above data stores. We wouldn't want to write any code related to admin tasks like backups, purging, maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jets3t - http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

We've used this and it works like a charm for S3.

I'm not sure I understand if you are looking for a framework that will work for both file-system storage and S3, but as unique as S3 is, I'm not sure that such a thing would exist.  Obviously with S3, backups and maintenance are handled for you.

Comment: We are actually looking for file system storage to start with before using amazon-s3 data store in the future.